# Call Lightning QuickAction from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction

I have 2 Lightning components as `QuickAction`.

The second one should be able to call the first one as a quick action as well (Modal).

Is there a way to do so ? `RedirectToComponent` will open it in a new page and it is not the wanted behaviour. (I'm currently using an org in Summer '17)

Comment: I'm not an UX designer, but, is there any reason why you want to open another modal instead of displaying the second component inside the same quick action? The lightning design system provides a nice [progress indicator](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator) which could improve the ergonomy. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: This is not possible. I agree with @MartinLezer with his approach.

Comment: When do you want it to be redirected or called ? on any event?